# PHP programm unable to consume JAX WS on Glassfish

Tags: php, service, web, glassfish, jax-ws

Try to consume a web service provided by a Java 1.6 based web application under glassfish 3.1 / windows server 2003. The web services is to be consumed by php script under linux which retrieves the WSDL by using the library php2WSDl.

Well the php script tries to call a web services method but does not
get any response like an acknowledge on the TCP level. The web services bases on SOAP 1.1
The same web application deployed on Tomcat 6.0 gives a response to the PHP script and
executes its progammed routine. What might be the problem?

If I use the web services META data like @WebMethod glassfish executes the the method but @Webparam parameters are always null like java.lang.String and java.util.Date though the parameters are filled by the php.

- What might be the reason for this problem?
- What solution to this problem would you suggest?

Comment: You need to give some material on this, no wsdl, no code nothing?